# How can I add an annotation for a property between two individuals using rdflib

Tags: python, owl, rdflib

I'm using rdflib in python to build a graph, and how can i use it to add an annotation for a property between two individuals.
For example, graph namespace is `<http//:example.com/test#>`, two individuals are `<http//:example.com/test#a>` and `<http//:example.com/test#a>`, one relation `<http//:example.com/test#rel>` between individual a and b. And an annotation property description for rel between a and b. The code in owl is shown below

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http//:example.com/test#a">
    <rel rdf:resource="http//:example.com/test#b"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<owl:Axiom>
    <owl:annotatedSource rdf:resource="http//:example.com/test#a"/>
    <owl:annotatedProperty rdf:resource="http//:example.com/test#rel"/>
    <owl:annotatedTarget rdf:resource="http//:example.com/test#b"/>
    <description rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">des</description>
</owl:Axiom>
```

And how can i use rdflib in python to build a graph like this.

Comment: rdflib is for RDF, your annotation is OWL - that means, you would have to add the set of 4 RDF triples representing the OWL annotation axiom. You can see the OWL2 RDF mapping here: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/

Comment: thx for solving my problem, and i can see annotation in protege.@UninformedUser